# What are the tier level breakdowns?

Tags: robocraft

Level x gets you into tier 2 battles.
Level y gets you into tier 3 battles.

What are x, y, etc?

This isn't posted anywhere in the game that I can see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you may have gotten the system completely wrong.

**Your player level is completely different to your tier.**
Your player level (thing at the top left-hand side) determines how big your robots can be (the amount of pFLOPS they can use). You can gain these by damaging enemies.

Your robot tier (separate for each robot you own) is determined by the blocks that you have placed on your robot; as otherwise known as a "Robot Ranking".
The higher tier weapons/hardware/blocks you place on it, the more it'll increase your robot ranking, and thus your tier is determined by how high your robot ranking is, based on Tier cut-offs, which are slightly less than double of the previous tier. *I do not know the exact numbers, but it is an accurate rough estimate.*

---

So, answering your question - Your player level does not determine which tier you can play; only how many pFLOPS worth of blocks you can use on your robot... And your robot tier determines which tier you're in.

So, there is no minimum player-level to go into any Tier. For all we know - There could be a Tier 7 player who has simply bought a robot from the Roboshop but yet have a player Level of 1.
*(Note: Robots purchased from the Roboshop will increase the player's pFLOPS limit (and not player level) to the value of the robot they purchased.)*

Comment: This answer is somewhat obsolete with the removal of tiers. (Yes, this answer was written by me)